# php + ajax insert into form

Tags: php, ajax

Hello i am learning to code and i have a problem with an ajax/php script

I am trying to insert data in a database without refreshing the page

here's the code:

```
<?php
require('../dbcon.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#paypay").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  var identifiant = $("#identifiant").val(); 
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    identifiant: identifiant,
                    password: password,
                    email: email,
                },
                success: console.log('aa'),

            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
     <?php

  
  if(!empty($_POST['inscription'])){
      if(!empty($_POST['identifiant']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['email']))
        {
              $identifiant = $_POST['identifiant'];
              $password = $_POST['password'];
              $email = $_POST['email'];            
            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres (identifiant, password, email, paysafecard, paypal, ip, status, snapchat, admin, freebet, vip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $req->execute(array(htmlspecialchars($identifiant), md5($password), htmlspecialchars($email), "désactivé", "désactivé", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, htmlspecialchars($_POST['snapchat']), 0, 1, 0));
        echo "ok";
        }
        
         else
        {
            
            echo "pas inscrit";
        }       
        
}

?>   
    
                    <form id="paypay" method="POST" action="">
                    <input type="text"  id="identifiant" name="identifiant" placeholder="Identifiant">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="MDP">
                    <input type="text" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="email">
                    <input type="submit" name="inscription"  id="inscription">
                    </form>
<a href="https://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>

<p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to remove the ajax script and the php script works well, but when i add it back, the php script doesn't work anymore.

Also when i check the success data from ajax in the console, it seems to be working so i don't really know what is wrong and what i could do

thanks mate

Comment: `success: console.log('aa')` would, I think, throw an error ~ wrap that in an anonymous ( or named ) function. If you are posting to the same page ( as it appears ) you cannot expect to use any return value from the PHP without further modifications to the code to strip extra output from any desired response. `MD5` is NOT safe to use when storing a user's password - use `password_hash` and `password_verify`

Comment: As you are using a `prepared statement` you should NOT use any functions which potentially modify the raw data that you use in the sql as any checks performed later would need to observe the same pattern of data manipulation ( ie: don't use `htmlspecialchars` on input data )

Comment: It would be useful if you were to check the browser console for any errors and edit the question to include these errors in support the question

Comment: thank you mate for the good advices

Comment: i tried to add another page insert.php with the php script because it was on the same page but it's still the same, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes here,

**First:** if you tried to `var_dump($_POST)` in php after form is submited over ajax you would see that there is no `$_POST['inscription']` in ajax post request, this means that code will stop here `if(!empty($_POST['inscription'])){`

**Second:** you are sending `$_POST['snapchat']` to database but that field doesn't exists in form

**Third:** in ajax `success: console.log('aa'),`, success is a function that is getting response back from php file so it must be used like

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Also separate file that will process php data from form, and don't use md5() for password

Here is those 2 working files
**form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#paypay").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $('#paypay').serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response[0] == 'error') {
                            $('#response-message').html(response[1]);
                        }
                        if (response[0] == 'success') {
                            $('#response-message').html(response[1]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="response-message"></div>

        <form id="paypay" method="POST">
            <input type="text" id="identifiant" name="identifiant" placeholder="Identifiant">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="MDP">
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" id="snapchat" name="snapchat" placeholder="Snapchat">
            <input type="submit" name="inscription" id="inscription">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and **test.php** where php logic is and connection to database so that you can insert data

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['identifiant']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['snapchat'])) {

    $identifiant = htmlspecialchars($_POST['identifiant']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $snapchat = htmlspecialchars($_POST['snapchat']);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    require('../dbcon.php');         
    
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO membres (identifiant, password, email, paysafecard, paypal, ip, status, snapchat, admin, freebet, vip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $req->execute(array($identifiant, $password, $email, "désactivé", "désactivé", $ip, 0, $snapchat, 0, 1, 0));
        
    // if record is inserted it should return last id inserted
    if ($bdd->lastInsertId() > 0) {
        echo json_encode(array("success", "Record inserted"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("error", "Failed to insert record"));
    }

} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error", "All fields are required"));
}
```

**EDIT:**
also you don't need those variables in ajax since you can simple pass form id which will take all data from form

```
//var identifiant = $("#identifiant").val(); // no need
//var password = $("#password").val(); // no need
//var email = $("#email").val(); // no need

$.ajax({
   url: "test.php",
   type: "POST",
   // this all can be replaced 
   //data: {
   //      identifiant: identifiant,
   //      password: password,
   //      email: email,
   //}
   // replaced with
   data: $('#paypay').serialize(),
```

Comment: thank you mate for the tips and for the working script i am new to this and it helped me a lot.

Comment: @centurionfeatures no problem, this is why many developers are here to help each others